# Аналог метода slice javascript

Tags: javascript, массивы

Как будет выглядеть функция, которая является полным аналогом метода slice? Какие параметры у нее должны быть?

Comment: Такие же параметры, как и у `slice`. + входящий массив (раз это функция). Логично же

Comment: и плюс сам массив

Comment: @ra.chobanyan  Вопрос бессмысленный, так как полный аналог  slice будет выглядеть как slice. В следующий раз попробуйте задать что-нибудь, как бы помягче сказать, , чтобы вас не обидеть, посодержательнее.

Comment: [пример в большинстве случае можно посмотреть в mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#Streamlining_cross-browser_behavior)

Comment: Ну почти такое же делает `splice`

Comment: @Yuri, не не не, splice делает совсем другое, slice - не меняет исходный массив, в отличие от

Comment: @Grundy, да? Запомню. Я, просто, всегда `slice` использовал)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Бессмысленный комментарий. Потому что дана задача написать функцию, которая аналогична методу. Чтобы отточить навыки свои.

Comment: **свои** навыки, а не наши. Мы-то можем написать даже аналог `new` оператора :)

Comment: @ra.chobanyan  И что что дано задание? Как это отразится на то, что функция, которая полностью аналогична функции slice будет выглядеть как slice? Глупой вопрос и такой же глупый ваш комментарий. Или же вы ожидали ответа, что аналогичная функция не будет выглядеть как slice?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow мне интересно, как обстоят дела со зрением? Написано четко два вопроса, их не видно? Если нет, то медицина в 21 веке творит чудеса. Достаточно ответить на них, а не глагольствовать тут, кого обидеть, кого не обидеть, Чей вопрос бессмысленный, чей комментарий бессмысленный. Если отталкиваться от моего вопроса, то именно твой комментарий бессмысленный и глупый, как и твои рассуждения.

Comment: @ra.chobanyan Я так понимаю, что до вас с первого раза не доходит, что функция, аналогичная slice, будет выглядеть как slice, а, следовательно, иметь те же самые параметры.  Удивляет лишь, что ваш вопрос сразу же не закрыли.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ может быть таким:

```js
let slice = Array.prototype.slice;

Array.prototype.mySliceImplement = function(...args){
  return slice.apply(this, args);
};

let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
console.info(arr.slice(2, 4)); // Original
console.info(arr.mySliceImplement(2, 4)); // My function
```

Comment: в чем смысл выноса slice в переменную? тогда уж `this.slice(...args)` делать

Comment: @Grundy, это был тонкий намёк на иронию, который этим комментом теряет остроту :)

Comment: Это было слишком тонко :-) в следующий раз не забудь табличку

Comment: @Grundy, уровень "английский" :) Что за табличка?

Comment: "Сарказм", "Ирония", и т.д. :)

Comment: @Grundy, ответы не позволяют вставить метку, а то так бы и сделал.